# Error after running middleman contentful

Tags: ruby, middleman, contentful

I try to use contentful CMS with middleman extension "middleman_contentful". I got this error after I run middleman contentful

> /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/middleman-core-3.3.11/lib/middleman-core/core_extensions/data.rb:114:in `[]=': no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)

anyone know why this happen?

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing you're code it's difficult to be sure why you're getting that error but one common reason for it is using an array as a hash.

```
person = [ {"name"=>"Jane Doe", "age"=>42, "nickname"=>"Joey"} ]
```

Check if you're calling a variable like `person` which is an `Array` that contains a `Hash` as `person['name']` as opposed to `person[0]['name']`. Which will allow you access the `Hash#[]` method.

Comment: I just add this to config.rb

 `activate :contentful do |f|
   f.space         = {events: 'space-id'}
   f.access_token  = 'some_access_token'
   f.content_types = { promo: 'content-type-id'}
 end`

Comment: Thanks for the update, great to hear you figured it out!